# Why is the maximum ffmpeg mjpeg quality so low?

Tags: ffmpeg, imagemagick, jpeg, mjpeg

I used ffmpeg to generate a one-frame mjpeg video at the maximum possible quality, like this:

```
ffmpeg -i reference.png -frames:v 1 -codec:v mjpeg -q:v 1 -an 1.mkv
```

I also made a reference conversion to jpeg using imagemagick, at 85% quality:

```
convert reference.png -quality 85 85.jpg
```

The resulting "1.mkv" is only 83K, despite the fact that 85.jpg is 88K - and that's not even the highest possible jpeg quality.

At 95% imagemagick produces a file of 120K, and 207K at 100%. (Though it should be noted that image quality does not improve above 95%.) Since ffmpeg is set to maximum quality, I would expect frames of around this size.

Why are ffmpeg's mjpeg frames so small?

Comment: Is your question about visual quality or output file size?  Possibly the file sizes are different because they use different jpeg libraries. ImageMagick uses libjpeg. I do not know what ffmpeg uses. So ffmpeg may get better compression. Is it a fair comparison between mjpeg and jpg? One is a motion jpeg and the other is a simple jpg.

Comment: I'm considering filesize to be a rough approximation of visual quality. The encoders surely are different, but since the difference here is so large, it can't be purely down to that. ffmpeg -q:v 1 should output the highest possible quality jpeg, and a 95% quality jpeg from imagemagick is 120K, way bigger than the 83K from ffmpeg. motion jpeg is just a sequence of jpeg images so the different formats should not be so significant.

Comment: 83K and 88K are not that different size when different compression tools are being used. Perhaps I misunderstand your issue.

Comment: They are similar except that ffmpeg is set to maximum quality and imagemagick only set to 85%. Imagemagick produces a 120K file at 95% and 207K at 100%.

Comment: As I said before, different compression tools may optimize differently. The quantization table are likely different.

Comment: That is not sufficient for such a large difference. ffmpeg's jpegs are obviously much more highly compressed.

Comment: ffmpeg's highest quality value may not compare to Imagemagick's -quality 100. ffmpeg may compress more but then may have lower visual quality. The higher the actual compression, the poorer the visual quality. Quality value is opposite to compression and file size. Larger quality values means less compression and higher file size. I will leave it at that and let others follow with their thoughts.

Comment: `ffmpeg` uses its own (M)JPEG encoder. `-qmin 2` is the default, so if you want to use `-q:v 1` you'll need to set `-qmin 1`, but the file size will likely not be anything near `convert` 100. Add `-huffman optimal` for additional optimization (this will not affect quality). Note that `ffmpeg` will output yuvj444p from an rgb input, while convert may output yuvj420p at < `-quality 90` (I didn't verify this behavior).

Comment: -qmin 1 makes a big difference, thank you, that's very useful. You're welcome to submit that as an answer.

Comment: I didn't add it to an answer because it didn't technically answer why the `ffmpeg` output is so much smaller in file size than `convert` (even with `-qmin 1 -q:v 1`). I don't know the answer to that and it would require a look at the source code of both. Also, it appears `-huffman optimal` is now the default so no need to add that with a recent version.